# Am I reading Normal Distribution table correctly?

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's say I have a normal distribution with mean = 5.

Say $P(X>9) = .2$. Then does the following hold?

$1 - P(X<9) = .2$

$P(X<9) = .8$

$\frac{9-5}{\sigma} = .7881$

Or, am I reading [this Normal Distribution table](https://f.hypotheses.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/253/files/2013/10/Capture-d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran-2013-10-15-a%CC%80-14.22.40.png) wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the normal distribution table wrongly. The values inside the table are the probabilities.

$0.8$ is between $0.7995$ and $0.8023$, hence

$$0.84<\frac{9-5}{\sigma}<0.85.$$